# Posso ter mais de um diretório Views em MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, view, organização-de-projeto

Estou transferindo meu projeto pra MVC, e gostaria de saber se pode ter mais de uma pasta `Views` no projeto, ou se tem como carregar um CSS fora do `BundleConfig`, ter uma página estática meio que vai *bugar* todas as minhas páginas.

Comment: Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode organizar do jeito que quiser. A disposição de onde ficam as coisas não importam. Claro que é muito fácil manter o padrão que o Visual Studio já sabe trabalhar bem. Não há problemas em trabalhar com páginas estáticas.

Quando for retornar a *view* pode fazer algo assim:

```
return View("~/Views/Cadatros/Cliente.cshtml")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ViewPath.cs).

Tem como configurar rotas também para direcionar da forma que deseja em pastas diferentes. Veja [`RazorViewEngine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.razorviewengine?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

[Dicas para aprender mais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/recommended-resources-for-mvc?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode carregar o CSS fora do BundleConfig, só inserir `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/seu-css.css")" rel="stylesheet" />` na view que deseja.